# experiencing issue with applying css background-attachment

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive-images

[image: this first image is actual output am now getting]

[image: the second image is my required output]

Here is the css I'm applied for a section to bring this background:

```
#banner{
  background: #242a33 url(../images/sliderbg.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I'm using the same css code for other sections it works fine. I don't know whats the problem here. BG image size is 1600px * 400px.

Comment: Which image is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Switch `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: contain;`. You may need to tinker with `background-position` and set it to `background-position: top;` to get the desired effect.

Comment: i want the image to cover entire width even zoom in and zoom out .  i tried contain already it brings the space or the image fixed not working

Comment: `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: You want to stick your code in a fiddle so I can take a look at it and stop having to guess?

Comment: i never used fiddle before but i put my code in respective fields, dont know how to insert images .  fiddle link  https://jsfiddle.net/y4o3q220/

Answer (score 0):

```
#Banner {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background: url('PathToImage');
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: hi i tried the above code  but when i zoom out the bg image slide to left but i want it to be fixed full width bg